# What is this sequence called?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

What is this called? Any tips on how to work with it? Any references?
$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}}{2 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{1-\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{2}}-\frac{1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}}{2 \sqrt{2}}}{2
   \sqrt{2}}+\frac{1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}}{2
   \sqrt{2}}-\frac{1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{1-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}}{2
   \sqrt{2}}}{2 \sqrt{2}}}{2 \sqrt{2}}+\cdots$$

**Edit** It comes from:
$$b(0)\text{:=}0;b(\text{n})\text{:=}\frac{1-b(n-1)}{2^{3/2}}+b(n-1)$$

Comment: So... does it keep going or does it just stop right there?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I goes as far as you want. This is 4 steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$a_1 = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
$$a_n = \frac{1- \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k}{2\sqrt{2}} = a_1(1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k)$$

$$a_n = a_1(1 - a_{n-1} -\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}a_k)= a_1(1 -\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}a_k) - a_1a_{n-1}$$
$$a_n = a_{n-1} - a_1a_{n-1} = (1 - a_1)a_{n-1}$$
$$a_n = (1 - a_1)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  let $\,\displaystyle c=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\,$, then the sum is $\,c(a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots)\,$ where $a_0=1$ and $a_{n}=a_{n-1}(1-c)$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] To address the part that was later edited into the question:

$$
b_n=c(1-b_{n-1})+b_{n-1} \iff b_n=(1-c)b_{n-1}+c \iff b_n-1=(1-c)(b_{n-1}-1)
$$

It then follows by telescoping that:

$$
b_n-1=(1-c)(b_{n-1}-1)=(1-c)^2(b_{n-2}-1)=\cdots=(1-c)^n(b_0-1)
$$